# How can an app on facebook page be set as landingpage?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

we wanted to set our app "Willkommen" on the following page as landingpage:

https://www.facebook.com/ProfileCare?sk=app_181088235298512

At the moment the wall is the landingpage.

Looking forward to helpful answers.

Best,
Kristina

Comment: I see, thanks so far! But, if you have already liked the page, then it is not the landingpage. Is there a possiblity to have it always as landing page, no matte if liked or not?

Answer (score 0):

"Willkommen", for me at least (UK), is the landing page.

Comment: I see, thanks so far! But, if you have already liked the page, then it is not the landingpage. Is there a possiblity to have it always as landing page, no matter if liked or not?

Answer (score 0):

For me also Willkommen is the landing page

However, to set the landing tab click on **Edit Page** and you find the option **Default Landing Tab**

Comment: I see, thanks so far! But, if you have already liked the page, then it is not the landingpage. Is there a possiblity to have it always as landing page, no matter if liked or not?

Answer (score 0):

You must open your Edit Page menu, then Manage Permissions and there choose your app from the Default landing tab list

Comment: I see, thanks so far! But, if you have already liked the page, then it is not the landingpage. Is there a possiblity to have it always as landing page, no matter if liked or not?

Comment: Setting the default landing tab is the only solution Facebook offers